# How do I get the file contents of a MultipartMemoryStreamProvider as a byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I have created a component that uploads files to a Web API controller using FormData.

How do I get the file contents from the MultipartMemoryStreamProvider as a byte array?

**Here is the Web Api method**

```
   public Task<IEnumerable<FileModel>> Post()
   {             
     if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {            
            var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileModel>>(t =>
            {

                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }

                FileDataBO filedata;
                var fileInfo = streamProvider.Contents.Select(i => {
                    //save to db
                    filedata = new FileDataBO ();
                    filedata.FileName = i.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                    filedata.FileType = "jpeg";

                    // HOW TO GET FILE CONTENT HERE??? IT SHOULD BYTE[]
                    //filedata.FileContent = ???

                    //TODO
                    //_fileDataService.SaveFile(filedata);    

                    return new FileModel(i.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName, 2048);
                });
                return fileInfo;
            });

            return task;
        }             
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }       
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to get the content by doing `i.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()`